# connecting postgresql and codeigniter

Tags: php, database, postgresql, codeigniter

I'm new using postgresql and I've been using Codeigniter for a year.

I have a small postgresql database and I wanna call it from Codeigniter.

In my database.php file I have this setup:

```
$active_group = 'default';
$query_builder = TRUE;

$db['default'] = array(
'dsn'   => 'pgsql:host=localhost;port=5432;dbname=test;user=postgres;password=aPass',
// 'dsn'    => '',
'hostname' => 'localhost',
'username' => 'postgres',
'password' => 'aPass',
'database' => 'test',
'dbdriver' => '',
'dbprefix' => '',
'pconnect' => FALSE,
'db_debug' => TRUE,
'cache_on' => FALSE,
'cachedir' => '',
'char_set' => 'utf8',
'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
'swap_pre' => '',
'encrypt' => FALSE,
'compress' => FALSE,
'stricton' => FALSE,
'failover' => array(),
'save_queries' => TRUE
  // 'port' => '5432'
);
```

In a controller I have this function:

```
public function dbtest(){

    $this->load->database();

    $feeds = $this->db->get('vts_feeds');
    echo $feeds;die();
}
```

The result I'm getting is:

```
An Error Was Encountered
You have not selected a database type to connect to.
```

Why is it not working?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try to set,

> dbdriver - The database type. ie: mysql, postgres, odbc, etc. Must be
>   specified in lower case.

More Info: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/configuration.html

**EDIT:** Try this config for `PDO` in postgres

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'pgsql:host=localhost;dbname=yourdb'; //set host
$db['default']['username'] = 'your username'; //set username
$db['default']['password'] = 'your password'; //set password
$db['default']['database'] = 'your database'; //set databse
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'pdo'; //set driver here
```

Comment: thx! I had to put pdo in order to work with the config I got. Do you know why does it not work if I put dbdriver = postgres, and just put dsn to blank?

Comment: @Limon See my Edited answer, this might help you, Best of luck

Answer (score 4):

Remove the 'dsn' string and change to `'dbdriver' => 'postgre'` in the config array.

Despite the CI docs stating the value should be `'postgres'` if you check the directory and file names in `system>database>drivers` the folder is actually called `'postgre'`, the file name `'postgre_driver.php'` and the class `'CI_DB_postgre_driver'` so we can assume the docs are wrong here. Weird this hasnt raised its ugly head before

Comment: it says "invalid DB driver". I left dsn in blank and changed dbdriver to "postgres"

Comment: Hmm strange. Do you have the driver file in the system database folder? This should just try to load the `CI_postgres_db_driver` file

Comment: Looking at the file structure it looks like the right driver value is `'postgre'` which is weird as the CI docs definitely say `'postgres'`. Try without the 's' and see if that helps - I updated my answer

Comment: yes, you are right. In CI docs there's a mistake, it is postgre and not postgres.

Comment: I upgraded your answer but I had used first the solution given by @BunnySunny

Answer (score 3):

I just did it right now.
You just leave :

```
$db['default']['dsn'] = '';
```

And set:

```
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'postgre';
```

Answer (score 1):

In the file `database.php` where it reads:

```
'dbdriver' => ' ',
```

Put the following argument:

```
'dbdriver' => 'pgsql',
```

Comment: for me it says "Invalid DB driver". My OS is cent os.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Try these steps

1. don't remove `dsn` string  add `port=>5432` to your config array
2. set dbdriver to `'dbdriver' => 'postgres'`
3. check your php.ini file if postgre extension is enabled or not `extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll`

Comment: the extension was already enabled. I have tried this way too but it's only working with dbdriver=> pdo and the dsn I mentioned

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you create a user in psql by using linux terminal then grant all access to this user? And then change the username and password at config database with that one.

Comment: Please use the comment section for follow up questions and note that this question has already been answered