# How to connect to POSTGRESQL in Codeigniter 3?

Tags: php, postgresql, codeigniter, tcp

I am trying to connect to PostgreSQL using Codeigniter framework.
Now in my **database.php**

I have the following code :

```
$active_group = 'default';
$query_builder = TRUE;

$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'postgres',
    'password' => '',
    'database' => 'fmsdb',
    'dbdriver' => 'postgre',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

But When I run my site in localhost, I get following database error :

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: pg_connect(): Unable to connect to PostgreSQL server: could
>   not connect to server: Permission denied Is the server running on host
>   "localhost" (::1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432? could
>   not connect to server: Permission denied Is the server running on host
>   "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
>
> Filename: postgre/postgre_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 154

I tried putting this in my PostgreSQL.conf file :

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29630851/connecting-postgresql-and-codeigniter

Comment: add postgreSQL port `$db['default']['port'] = 5432;` also enabled the ext from php ini. `extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll`

Comment: how to enable this extension in centos7

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First enable `Postgresql` extension in `php.ini`

**`extension=php_pgsql.dll`**

You also can enable `Postgresql` extension for PDO as well.

**`extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll`**

---

```
$db['default'] = array(
    'port'   => 5432, # Add 
);
```

OR

```
$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => 'pgsql:host=localhost;port=5432;dbname=database_name', 
    'dbdriver' => 'pdo',
);
```

---

[Database-configuration in codeigniter.com](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/configuration.html#database-configuration)

Comment: i think my pgsql is already loaded as i have installed phpPGAdmin and its working fine

Comment: u can also suggest to restart APACHE, this will help to others. i think. :)

Answer (score 3):

**Tested with Codeigniter 4, PHP 7.3 and PostgreSQL 9.3.5**:

1) Enable in your php.ini

```
extension=php_pgsql.dll
```

2) In app/Config/Database class override your $default property as follows:

```
/**
 * The default database connection.
 *
 * @var array
 */

public $default = [
    'DSN'      => '',
    'hostname' => 'your_host',
    'username' => 'your-user',
    'password' => 'your-password',
    'database' => 'your-database',
    'DBDriver' => 'postgre',
    'DBPrefix' => '',
    'pConnect' => false,
    'DBDebug'  => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cacheOn'  => false,
    'cacheDir' => '',
    'charset'  => 'utf8',
    'DBCollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swapPre'  => '',
    'encrypt'  => false,
    'compress' => false,
    'strictOn' => false,
    'failover' => [],
    'port'     => 5432, //the default port 
];
```

Answer (score 1):

1. First enable these two extensions

   ```
   extension=php_pgsql.dll
   extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll
   ```
2. Then restart apache
3. Add **$db['default']['port'] = 5432** in database.php file with all other codes.

Comment: I am using centos 7 will these settings be same  ?

Comment: i think my pgsql is already loaded as i have installed phpPGAdmin and its working fine

Comment: check your phpinfo. if pdo_pgsql & pgsql are available, then i think will be no error. if not run yum list "php*" for available php packages. here you found package like php5-pgsql/ php-pdo_pgsql/ php-pgsql. then run install the package yum install php-pgsql & yum install php-pdo_pgsql. then restart apache.